# Filling media wiki parser function input with Semantic forms

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I have a parser function for integrating with [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira).
So when I provide  {{#jira : JIRA-223}} the parser functions would fetch the Type and Status of the issue corresponding to the jira issue id ( in eg : JIRA-223 ) and displays in the page.

I wanted to capture the Jira issue id from a Semantic form. So that the jira issue id is a semantic property and is displayed in a more user friendly manner.

Is there a way to achieve this. I tried with materials available and gone through usage of some extension and their code but was not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could achieve this by enhancing the template which is attached to the form

1. In the template it had the property to hold multiple ids ( JIRA Ids).
2. Added the parser function notation within the template and used the id reference within the parser function.
3. Attached the template to the form.
4. While creating the page using the template the parser function is populated in the page from the template, which in turn listed the html containing enhanced detailed on the jira id.

Usage : {{#jira: {{#arraymap:{{{Jira_id|}}}|,|x|[[Jira_id::x]]}} }}